# Postgres backup using pg_basebackup is failed

Tags: postgresql, database-administration

We are taking daily backup using pg_basebackup.

from two days ago it has been failing. we are using standalone environment.

error details

> pg_basebackup: error: FATAL:  number of requested standby connections exceeds max_wal_senders (currently 10)
> FATAL:  number of requested standby connections exceeds max_wal_senders (currently 10)

Answer (score 1):

There are already too many replication connections to that database. Either terminate some, or increase `max_wal_senders` and restart PostgreSQL.

I would query `pg_stat_activity` to find the offending connections and use `pg_terminate_backend` to terminate them

Comment: Hi Laurenz, Thx for your prompt response and can you please tell me the how to find replication connections using pg_stat_activity

Comment: Hi Laurenz, I checked in database with backend_type='walsender' but there is zero records that means in my db there is no replication connection. Please confirm this is correct

Comment: You don't show the complete query, but if it didn't cause an error, it should be correct. Perhaps you were looking at the wrong place, for example on the standby database, or your database user lacks the permission to see the data of these sessions. Use a superuser to be certain.

Comment: We are using the standalone server. No standby

Comment: As I said, you may lack the permissions. Use a superuser. Also, perhaps these many replication connections are not always there. The error is crystal clear: there were more replication connections than `max_wal_senders` allows.

Answer (score 0):

You should extend your max_wal_replication slots in postgresql.conf. Here is a code to perform this change in linux terminal:

```
sed -i "s/max_replication_slots = 10/max_replication_slots = 20/g" postgresql.conf
```